# Partial truth values?

Tags: logic, soft-question, propositional-calculus

In his essay *The Relativity of Wrong*, Isaac Asimov famously wrote:

> When people thought the Earth was flat, they were wrong. When people thought the Earth was spherical, they were wrong. But if you think that thinking the Earth is spherical is just as wrong as thinking the Earth is flat, then your view is wronger than both of them put together.

In mathematics and formal logic, at least according to every textbook I have read, a valid statement may hold exactly one of two truth values - *true* or *false*. However, just as "the earth is flat" and "the earth is spherical" are not equally wrong, there are mathematical statements which, though *false*, can be comparatively *more* or *less* false.

For example take the statements:
$$(1)\qquad\forall x\in\mathbb{N}.\frac{x}{2}\in\mathbb{N}$$
$$(2)\qquad\forall x\in\mathbb{R}.\frac{x}{2}\in\mathbb{N}$$
$(1)$ is false if $\exists x\in\mathbb{N}:2\nmid x$, and $(2)$ is false if $\exists x\in\mathbb{R}:2\nmid x$. Since both of these conditions hold $(1)$ and $(2)$ are both false. However, $(1)$ is *much* closer to being true than $(2)$, on account of there being uncountably more counterexamples to $(2)$ than to $(1)$. Furthermore, for exactly half of all $x\in\mathbb{N}$, the statement "$2\mid x$" is true. It then seems reasonable to say that $(1)$ is exactly *half* true (by which it is also *half* false). This follows from the fact that every other natural number *is* divisible by two, which implies that as a subset $X\subset\mathbb{N}$ grows to encompass all $\mathbb{N}$, the ratio between the even numbers $x\in X:2\mid x$ and odd numbers $x\in X:2\nmid x$ converges to $\frac{1}{2}$.

Intuitively, it would follow that any statement which can be phrased as "Object (domain) - Relation - Object" (i.e. $x\mid y,\quad a\subset b\iff x=3,\quad a\ast b=b\ast c\implies a=c$, etc.) can be assigned a truth value between $0$ (completely false, not at all true), and $1$ (completely true, not at all false).

If we permit this, then statements which could not otherwise be evaluated logically, including certain nonsense statements like the liar's paradox, become amenable to formal logic. Likewise, should a false statement have an underlying truth to it (as indicated by a nonzero truth value), the domain can be adjusted until the truth value reaches $1$.

I find this an incredibly useful notion, both in the steps leading up to a proof and in connecting mathematics to everyday life.

However, I am not sure how to make the notion of fractional truth values rigorous. Is there a good way to formalize partial truth so that it is consistent with itself and with accepted mathematical logic? Ideally, I would like to *extend* the notion of truth values to encompass all potential propositions, rather than challenge extant logic.

---

As a side note, I think this is very similar - though not quite identical - to probability, and certain ideas carry over quite well. For example the truth value of $A\land B$ (assuming $A$ and $B$ are independent of each other) is equal to the product of the truth values of $A$ and $B$ (you can test this with propositions about objects in one or more finite sets) - similar to how the probability of two independent events occurring simultaneously is the product of there probabilities.

---

As a side side note, if there is an airtight way to formalize this, it might provide a valid basis for challenging Tarski's undefinability theorem - although the definition of truth would be invariably circular. I think it might also require using real or extended real numbers to encode for statements rather than standard Gödel numbering, but I don't know enough about incompleteness to say for certain.

Comment: See [Fuzzy logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuzzy_logic) and [Many-valued logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-valued_logic).

Comment: Maybe useful : [Fuzzy Sets and Systems](https://www.sciencedirect.com/journal/fuzzy-sets-and-systems) and e.g. Barnabas Bede, [Mathematics of Fuzzy Sets and Fuzzy Logic](https://books.google.it/books?id=LCK6BQAAQBAJ&pg=PA1), Springer (2013)

Comment: Maybe also look up Kripke models, especially the interpretation in terms of partial knowledge of a system.

Comment: @R.Burton Not quite the same thing, but you may find [this talk on Logical Induction](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UOddW4cXS5Y) interesting and entertaining.

Comment: Yes the first thing I also thought of was fuzzy logic.

Comment: I suggest taking a look at Merrie Bergmann's "An Introduction to Many-Valued and Fuzzy Logic" : https://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Many-Valued-Fuzzy-Logic-Derivation/dp/0521707579  Also, Petr Hajek's later work in this area has importance, but it's generally more advanced.  Also, many books on 'fuzzy logic' use the term more in the broad sense of having a fuzzy set theory and things based on that, but the above refer more to formal logic proper.  I think you put things well as to why degrees of truth have their uses even in mathematics.

Answer (score 2):

> When people thought the Earth was flat, they were wrong. When people thought the Earth was spherical, they were wrong. But if you think that thinking the Earth is spherical is just as wrong as thinking the Earth is flat, then your view is wronger than both of them put together.

I think Asimov was just being provocative here. Perfectly flat and perfectly spherical by no means exhausts all of the infinite possibilities. Clearly, neither is the case. Both are false. That in itself does not mean that some weird new logic of "partial truths" or degrees of truth and falsity is called for. Classical logic (the basis for most if not all of modern mathematics, science an technology) is more than up to the job of making sense of the constantly changing shape of the earth with its flattened poles, drifting continents, erosion, etc.

Comment: Well, it depends, actually - topologically speaking, Earth is indeed a sphere (up to homeomorphism, which is as good as $=$ in topology). As for flat - if we consider Earth a smooth manifold, the it is at least locally flat (ie diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$). Sorry, couldn't resist teasing a little ;-)

Comment: This comment made my day.

Comment: @DanChristensen - The Asimov quote is only meant to get the general idea across;  the point of the question is that while two mathematical statements may both be false, they need not be equally so. For example consider $\forall x\in\mathbb{R}.x^2=a\implies x=\sqrt{a}$ and $\forall x\in\mathbb{R}.x^2=a\implies x=\frac{a}{2}$. Any mathematician would agree that both statements are technically incorrect, but few would assert that the first is just as incorrect as the second. What I am looking for is a way to make this distinction rigorous.

Comment: @R.Burton  We are not assigning part-marks on some pop quiz here. I really doubt that any mathematician would talk about degrees of incorrectness in this case. Both statements are false, period.

Comment: @DanChristensen I'm not arguing that both statements are not false, nor am I arguing that mathematics doesn't get along fine relying on binary truth values. What I am saying is that by regarding both statements as totally false, without any further qualification, you are are throwing away useful information. It isn't incorrect to say they are both false, it's just less useful than specifying the extent and manner in which each is false.

Comment: Suppose we had a machine that picked out a prime number at random when run.  But, all of the designers of the machine M are dead, didn't leave notes for us, and no one knows about prime numbers.  Person A predicts the behavior of the machine by saying 'the machine picks out a member of the odd numbers.' and creates a model A' of M on that basis.  Person B predicts the behavior of the machine by saying 'it picks out a member of the natural numbers', and builds a model B' on that basis.  Both people said correct statements, both models are wrong.  But, is model B' just as good as model A'?

Comment: @DougSpoonwood A' will sometimes be wrong, but only when the output is 2 (highly unlikely though it may be). B' will always be right since the prime numbers are a subset of the natural numbers.What more is there to be said? There is no need to imagine any "partial truths" or "degrees of truth" here.

Comment: @DanChristensen No, B' won't always be right necessarily.  Composite numbers could get picked out.  It's easy to make statements about such systems.  "Model A'  is better than model B'."  Is that true or false?  It seems partially true in that model A' may get primes more often.  But, it seems partially false in that model B' might pick out 2.  Also, by forbidding 'partial truths' and 'degrees of truth' you throw terms like 'very', 'often', 'many', and the like out semantically.  Like '4 is very close to 1 in the natural number sequence' isn't true or false classically speaking.

Comment: @DougSpoonwood In your example, B' says that the outputs (always prime numbers) will always be natural numbers. This will always be true.

Comment: @DanChristensen I guess I wasn't speaking clearly.  Person B built B' on the basis of the conclusion that the machine output members of the natural numbers (B doesn't know about prime numbers).  Some machine that outputs some subset of the natural numbers, by no means seems likely to only output prime numbers.